# Using ufw (UncomplicatedFirewall) as an api

Tags: python, ubuntu

I know that ufw is written in python. Is it possible to use ufw as an api via python?

Comment: I'm sure it's *possible*, but given how poorly this code was written, it might not be *probable.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, the `ufw` executable is just a thin wrapper around a python package with the same name. I'm not aware of any documentation, but you can just poke around the source and have a look how everything works. Find the `ufw` script location using `which ufw` and the package location by starting the python interpreter, importing the `ufw` module and asking it for its import path:

```
simon@mymachine:~$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ufw
>>> ufw.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ufw/__init__.pyc'
>>>
```

Comment: An example on how to add a new rule?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. But look at the `ufw` script and find out what it does when you call `ufw allow` or `ufw insert`.

Answer (score 4):

I created a wrapper, easyufw, to enable the use of ufw as an api.

Blog post [here](http://dhj.io/posts/2016/09/14/easy-ufw-api/).

Repository [here](https://gitlab.com/dhj/easyufw).

### setup

You can pull easyufw from GitLab like this:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/dhj/easyufw.git
```

You will also need ufw and you will need to run easyufw
with root privileges because ufw requires it:

```
sudo pip install ufw
sudo python
```

### try it

Once you are set up you can type
these commands into a python terminal to get a feel for how
easy it is.

#### Note the interface is live -- there is no dry run so it will actually run the commands you give it.  Be careful.

```
import easyufw.easyufw as ufw

print ufw.status()
ufw.enable() # enable the firewall
ufw.deny('22/tcp') # disable ssh -- could disable active sessions!
ufw.allow('22/tcp') # enable ssh -- '22' alone or as int includes tcp and udp
ufw.delete(22) # delete all rules for port 22 -- int required
ufw.disable() # this will leave your firewall disabled! (default in ubuntu, but IMO, not smart)
```

You can also run any arbitrary command with `ufw.run` like `ufw.run('allow from 207.46.232.182')` (after `import easyufw.easyufw as ufw`)

That's it.  Hope it is useful.