# How to use the Python UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall) API in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, firewall, iptables

I use UFW on Ubuntu 12.04 to allow and deny IP addresses to ports from the command line.

How can I use the API to do the following in Python?

```
$ sudo ufw status 
$ sudo ufw allow from 207.46.232.182
```

Currently I am just making system calls from Python.

Is there any web page or blog that describes how to use the API?  I could not find any.

by default, I can use:

```
import ufw
```

Comment: [Learn to use the source, Luke](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/learn-to-read-the-source-luke.html)!

Comment: This is a duplicate (by just a few weeks) of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170551/using-ufw-uncomplicatedfirewall-as-an-api/39511797#39511797  I went ahead and put my answer there (since you can't duplicate answers and it was asked first).  I think it will help people looking for ufw as an api.  Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39511797/1259706